# break js to files with $(document).ready() but keep scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I would like to break my javascript code to several .js files. Each of those .js has code that need to be inside the $(document).ready(..). So in each file a new $(document).ready(..) will start.

How could I call from filea.js functions declared in fileb.js (both inside a $(document).ready block) ?

If this is not possible, can you propose an alternative?
Thank you.

Edit: I would like to clarify that I would like to avoid using the global scope. I was hoping something in the line of using named functions as handlers for the event but I can't really see how to do it.

Comment: [I would make it a jQuery plugin. This allows for a global scope, and you can call them from anywhere.](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy. why make things so complicated? just wrap the code with `$(document).ready()` inside the function. not outside. see my answer below.

Comment: @gdoron: Complicated? `$.fn.myPlugin = function () { alert('This is global');}` That's complicated? It's less code than your answer.

Comment: Piggy backing on the jQuery object just to get global scope seems a little dubious. If the functions are related, they should probably have their own namespace.

Comment: @Douglas you're probably right about the namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really can't get away from declaring a global. Creating a single global isn't so bad, you can then namespace all your functions under it.

Put this in something like a main.js file, so you can keep your shared functions here:

```
// name this something unique to your page/site/app
var MYAPP = {};

// now we can attach functions to it

MYAPP.funcA = function() { /* ... */ };
MYAPP.funcB = function() { /* ... */ };
```

Then, in each of your anonymous functions you can access MYAPP.funcA(), MYAPP.funcB(), etc. You can also modify MYAPP on the fly to add functions, properties, etc.

In the end you have a single global (darn it!), but if you've named it properly you are creating a global namespace where your app code can safely reside.

Answer (score 4):

You can make a local variable global with

```
window.globalname = localname;
```

Remember that functions are variables.

Comment: Please don't suggest using global variables. though here it sounds fine, but it's not best practice.

Comment: @gdoron your answer also defines global variables. This answer is actually better, because it is explicit that they are global.

Comment: I'll probably go with globals even I'm sure something better exists. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the files are loaded in order (i.e. functions in `filea.js` get loaded before `fileb.js` calls them, you should be fine.

In order to make sure files load their dependencies first, you could consider require.js or head.js

I've had luck with the latter: http://headjs.com/

Comment: Thanks for the headjs, I suppose it's similar to jquery's .getScript(). The problem is that functions declared inside filea.js are not seen by fileb.js. Perhaps because they are treated as declared in 2 different anonymous functions.